# AngularJS call method from controller in directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem: I use Angular and I need to use `pushMsg` method but I don't know how can I call it, `boxCtrl.pushMsg(msg)` does not work.

```
app.directive("fileread", function (socket) {
return {
    scope: {
        fileread: "="
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
        element.bind("change", function (changeEvent) {
        var msg = { author: 'me', class: 'me' };
           // WHAT HERE???????
        });
    }
}
});

boxCtrl = function (socket, $scope) {
    this.messages = [];
}

boxCtrl.prototype = {
    pushMsg: function (message) {
        this.messages.push(message);
    }
}

app.controller('boxCtrl', boxCtrl);
```

Comment: pass function to directive scope or put it in a service to share anywhere in app

Comment: should also use `ng` event directives as much as possible , in your case `ng-change`. As soon as you add your own event handler you get into needing to notify angular of the event with `$apply` or `$timeout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create an isolated scope and pass it as an attribute:

```
app.directive("fileread", function (socket) {
return {
    scope: {
        fileread: "=",
        pushMessage: "="
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
        element.bind("change", function (changeEvent) {
        var msg = { author: 'me', class: 'me' };
        scope.pushMessage(msg);
        });
    }
}
});
```

And in your HTML:

```
<div fileread="..." push-message="pushMsg">
```

---

Edit: your controller should be something like this:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.messages = [];

  $scope.name = function(msg) {
    $scope.messages.push(msg);
    $scope.$apply(); //I think you need this to update the UI (not sure though)
  }
})
```

Comment: Now I get error: "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'pushMessage' of object #<Scope> is not a function"

Comment: Sprry my mistake, the HTML needs to be changed convert camel case to - separated words (I've edited the answer)

Comment: Ok better :) but now i get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined" it no see this.messages value i think :(

Comment: Use $scope instead of this, let me update the answer

Comment: hmm ok so I shouldn't use prototype? its better to add all in Ctrl without prototype?

Comment: I don't know the best answer to that question, but all examples I've seen for creating controllers are some variation of this way.